# Twitter share link in new window with sizes

Tags: javascript, twitter

I found an advice in stackoverflow here is my implementation:

```
<li class='list__item'><a href='http://twitter.com/share' onclick='window.open(this.href, 'mywin','left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0'); return false;' title='Twitter' class='icon icon_twitter'></a></li>
```

But for some reason it just open window in the same tab. What's wrong?
**Edit:** class is for css-design of link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use target `target="_blank"` OR target `target="_new"`. You can refer to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dimomohit/xb814f5g/)

Comment: Your answer is ok, but I've decided to choose this variant http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/dimomohit/xb814f5g/1/. You are facing error because go ' is closing onclick='window.open(this.href, '. You should have used onclick='window.open(this.href, "my win". Hope this help you.

Comment: This will help you better Write this code <li class='list__item'><a href='http://twitter.com/share' onclick='window.open(this.href, "mywin","toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400"); return false;' title='Twitter' class='icon icon_twitter'>NEW Win</a></li> OR Refer this http://jsfiddle.net/dimomohit/xb814f5g/3/